# Configure WordPress Installation autoinstalls via Softaculous in WHCMS

Tags: hosting, configuration

I'm trying to create a fully managed hosting package for my customers within whmcs without giving them cPanel and WordPress admin credentials. Ideally, upon purchase of a hosting package in whmcs, I'd like for two credentials to be created: the admin credential to be sent to me (the designer/hosting provider) and a user with the WordPress Editor role to be sent to the customer.

I found the tutorial for setting up the Softaculous auto-installer in whmcs, but I'm not sure where to go (or even dig) to tweak it. If anyone can give me some direction (or even tell me what to research), I'd be grateful!

Comment: Neither WHMCS or Softaculous are WP software, you will need to refer to their docs or configuration for support

Comment: Sigh, okay - whmcs support basically told me the same thing...back to Google we go...

Comment: Hey man, I've been thinking about this thread for the past few days and I think in the future, I'd prefer if you would offer some instruction on how I could improve my question rather than closing it outright. Reason being: closing questions outright from those new to the forum communicates that the site is only reserved for questions that meet all of a rather subjective interpretation of criteria. If we fail to meet said criteria, we get locked. This creates a stigma that the site is more of a 'secret club' than a place where people can grow and learn as developers.

Comment: That said, I think due to my focus of my question being on Softaculous rather than WP is what made it lock-worthy. In the end, this issue actually turned out to be a WHM/cPanel setup task combined with full cPanel, MySQL db, and WP backups. The idea is that new accounts are created in WHM, and then migrated with the backup cPanel and WP data (For anyone actually interested in the answer). Also...I wish I had seen that stack exchange had a 'webmasters' site. Really should have posted this question there.

Comment: Comments are not the place for this discussion, to discuss the site itself you should open a question on the meta stack at https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/, otherwise refer to the links in the closure box at the top